# All rows after first file off by one row

Tags: vba, excel, offset

I have a code which prints out one cell of a name in column 1 and 4 and the information corresponding to those names in column 2 and 3 which take up many rows.

The first file works well but all of the subsequent ones are printing one row lower than they should be. I have been playing with it and I imagine it is an easy fix of a +1 somewhere it shouldn't be or needing to take away the +1 for the following files.. but I cannot find it. Here is an image of what is happening. My code is provided below. Section (5) is where i print the info in columns 1 and 4. Any ideas?

[image]

**FULL CODE:**

```
Option Explicit

Sub LoopThroughDirectory()

    Dim objFSO As Object
    Dim objFolder As Object
    Dim objFile As Object
    Dim MyFolder As String
    Dim StartSht As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet
    Dim WB As Workbook
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim LastRow As Integer, erow As Integer
    Dim Height As Integer
    Dim RowLast As Long

    'turn screen updating off - makes program faster
    'Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'location of the folder in which the desired TDS files are
    MyFolder = "C:\Users\trembos\Documents\TDS\progress\"

    'Set StartSht = ActiveSheet
    Set StartSht = Workbooks("masterfile.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1")

    'create an instance of the FileSystemObject
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    'get the folder object
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(MyFolder)
    i = 1

    'loop through directory file and print names
'(1)
    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
        If LCase(Right(objFile.Name, 3)) = "xls" Or LCase(Left(Right(objFile.Name, 4), 3)) = "xls" Then
'(2)
            'print file name to Column 1
            Set WB = Workbooks.Open(fileName:=MyFolder & objFile.Name)
            Set ws = WB.ActiveSheet
'(3)
            'copy HOLDER column from F11 (11, 6) until empty
            With ws
                LastRow = GetLastRowInColumn(ws, "A")
                .Range(.Cells(11, 6), .Cells(LastRow, 6)).Copy
            End With

    Dim destination
    LastRow = GetLastRowInColumn(StartSht, "B")
    Set destination = StartSht.Range("B" & LastRow).Offset(1)
            'print HOLDER column to column 2 in masterfile in next available row
            destination.PasteSpecial
'(4)

            'ReDefine the destination range to paste into Column C
            LastRow = GetLastRowInColumn(StartSht, "C")
            Set destination = StartSht.Range("C" & LastRow).Offset(1)

            With ws
                'copy CUTTING TOOL column from F11 (11, 7) until empty
                LastRow = GetLastRowInColumn(ws, "G")
                'print CUTTING TOOL column to column 3 in masterfile in next available row
                .Range(.Cells(11, 7), .Cells(LastRow, 7)).Copy _
                    destination:=destination
            End With
'(5)
            With WB
               'print TDS information
                For Each ws In .Worksheets
                        'print the file name to Column 1
                        StartSht.Cells(i + 1, 1) = objFile.Name
                        'print TDS name to Column 4
                        With ws
                            .Range("J1").Copy StartSht.Cells(i + 1, 4)
                        End With
                        i = GetLastRowInSheet(StartSht) + 1
                'move to next file
                Next ws
'(6)
                'close, do not save any changes to the opened files
                .Close SaveChanges:=False
            End With
        End If
    'move to next file
    Next objFile
    'turn screen updating back on
    'Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1
'(7)
End Sub


Function GetLastRowInColumn(theWorksheet As Worksheet, col As String)
    With theWorksheet
        GetLastRowInColumn = .Range(col & .Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
    End With
End Function

Function GetLastRowInSheet(theWorksheet As Worksheet)
Dim ret
    With theWorksheet
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
            ret = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                          After:=.Range("A1"), _
                          Lookat:=xlPart, _
                          LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                          SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                          SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                          MatchCase:=False).Row
        Else
            ret = 1
        End If
    End With
    GetLastRowInSheet = ret
End Function
```

Comment: After you open the source file, you then have the code `Set ws = WB.ActiveSheet` so it looks like you only get values from the active sheet. However, in section (5) you then loop through all the sheets in `WB` which looks like an inconsistency. Shouldn't section (5) also just look at `WB.ActiveSheet`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the variable `i` to track which row you should fill in columns A and D. You initialise `i = 1` and then add 1 every time you write to the sheet `.Cells(i + 1,...`. But you also add 1 when you update the variable `i = GetLastRowInSheet(StartSht) + 1`

I suggest you initialise `i = 2` and then write to the `i` row

```
'(5)
        With WB
           'print TDS information
            For Each ws In .Worksheets
                    'print the file name to Column 1
                    StartSht.Cells(i, 1) = objFile.Name
                    'print TDS name to Column 4
                    With ws
                        .Range("J1").Copy StartSht.Cells(i, 4)
                    End With
                    i = GetLastRowInSheet(StartSht) + 1 ' this gets the row number for the next file
            'move to next file
            Next ws
```

Comment: This works perfectly. Thank you for explaining it so well. You're a very good teacher